# Почему - Робинзон?

Tags: имена-собственные

Кто не знает Робинзона Крузо? Сейчас слово "робинзон" уже стало нарицательным для обозначения людей, выживающих на необитаемом острове, а их приключения называют робинзонадой.
Но ведь героя Д. Дефо правильно зовут не Робинзон, а Р**о**бинсон - вполне обычной английское имя, сокращенно - Робин (кстати, интересно, Робин Гуда полностью тоже звали Робинсон?). Но откуда взялось и, главное, закрепилось в языке такое искаженное прочтение имени?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Робинсон" - строго говоря это фамилия, которую сам герой сделал именем. Есть версия, что это фамилия по матери, тогда как "Крузо" - по отцу, немцу, но подтвердить не могу, это якобы осталось в черновиках.
По другой версии его звали Робин Робинсон Крузо, т.е. имя просто совпало с основой первой, материнской, фамилии. Возможно, этот секрет раскрывался в третьей, полулегендарной части приключений (написанной уже якобы перед самой смертью автора, много после после "второй и последней"), успеха совсем уже не имевшей, и на русский так и не переведенной, но иногда упоминаемой в полных собраниях сочинений, изданных в прошлом веке.

Строго говоря, даже в английском фамилия Робинзон произносится она с побочным ударением на последним слоге, как и большинство подобных многосложных фамилий на "-son". Но дело даже не в этом побочном ударении. В какой-то момент была мода все фамилии героев переводных произведений слегка "офрацуживать"; англоязычных в особенности, там влияние французского было особенно сильно. Отсюда, имхо, и звонкое З, и ударение на последнем слоге. Так и закрепилась. В английском современная традиция позволяет произносить с разными ударениями. 
(+)
Ха!
Оказывается, в Википедии есть сноска, подтверждающая основную мою версию просхождения:

> > > ↑ где Робинзон (англ. Robinson) — имя по девичьей фамилии матери героя (распространённый способ именования в англоязычных странах), а Крузо — фамилия, происходящая от немецкой фамилии Крейцнер (нем. Kreutznaer)

Интересно, откуда они это взяли, есть ли прямое доказательство... 
Не могу сейчас из-за технических проблем рыться в интернете. Надо бы посмотреть, как называли Робинзона в семье и на судне. Не помню...

Answer (score 2):

Не следует забывать, что, согласно авторскому праву, писатель может давать героям имена, может и необычные, но согласующиеся с условиями и характером  действий героев. Вспомним Стародума из Недоросли. В нашем издании книги Д.Дефо имя Робинзон проходит, как говорится, от корки до корки без намека на другие имена. Ударение на последнем слоге обусловлено не влиянием французов, а структурой слова. Это слово состоит из двух: Робин и зон, где: Робин - это имя отца, а зон - это сын. Практически это отчество, вроде наших Петрович (сын Петра), Иванович. Но в качестве примера приведу построение тюркских имен. Полное имя: Ибрагим Али-оглы, которое означает: Ибрагим сын Али. На что падает ударение в этом имени?  - на оглы, то есть на сына. Тоже и в Робинзоне. Но автор это отчество сделал именем. Так что матушка героя здесь не причем.  
Фамилия Крузо к батюшке отношения не имеет. Этой фамилией Д. Дефо намекнул читателям на обстоятельства жизни героя. Крузо - это круизёр, путешественник, что-ли.

Comment: Простите, а камим орбьразам тюрские имена могли повлиять на Робинзона? Что-то у вас концы с концами не сходятся. 
Я у ж не говорю, что далеко не во всех тюрских ударение на последнем слоге.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю behemothus(u). Тюркские имена могли и не влиять на Робинзона. Просто зон (сын) является указателем на место одного из членов семьи в своей семье. Представляете, и у тюрков тоже. Рассудим  логически: в семье Робина-отца куча сыновей и одного назвали Робин. Как его должны отличать окружающие: соседи, блюстители порядка? Правильно: Робин-сын. Где здесь ударение? На сыне. Вот вам и Робинзон. У англичан наследство отца доставалось только старшему сыну, остальные (достигшие совершеннолетия) должны были убираться из дома. И кто куда. Робин-сын подался в круизёры. Вот на этой базе и дал писатель Д.Дефо имя и фамилию (практически кличку, как и у нас) своему герою. 
Но, обыкновенно, сыновья вырастали, обзаводились детьми и окружающие говорили: джоновы дети, робинсоновы дети. Где ставили ударение? На Робине, потому как Он -  отец; не Джон, не Гарри, а Робин. Далее.  Были ли у англичан в те времена паспорта? Вряд ли. Но когда пришла пора идентифицировать всех подданных королевства, то его детей в паспортах записывали: Мартин (Вилли и т.д.) Робинсон. Ударение на робин. Кстати, как написать в романе сына сон или зон - прерогатива автора, тем более, что с и з часто замещают друг друга. А может это трактовка переводчика.

**Обновление**

Уважаемый behemothus, ну зачем Вы так нервно... Практически я ни от чего не отказываюсь, но должен внести кое-какие уточнения. Роясь в инете, я наткнулся на "SHERWOOD-таверна. Литературно-исторический форум "Средневековье. Средневековые имена Medieval and renessanse names ". То, что я чисто интуитивно синтезировал из обрывков своих знаний нашло подтверждение в материалах этого форума. В качестве уточнения скажу, что Вы были правы в первой строчке своего первого ответа. В традиции небедных семей Англии была дача имен своими фамилиями и имя-фамилия со временем стало обычным. Поэтому - Робинсон. Но с легкой руки Д.Дефо, а не потому что мама. Кстати, Робин - это одна из форм имени Роберт (там же, в форуме). И еще: я бы рекомендовал зайти на форум на стр. 12. Интересно и познавательно.

Comment: >Тюркские имена могли и не влиять на Робинзона  
  
Они ***не могли*** влиять. 
Больше ничего сказать не могу, потому что назвать своим именем ваши утверждения не позволяет администрация.

Comment: Уважаемый @behemothus, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

"Это слово состоит из двух: Робин и зон, где: Робин - это имя отца, а зон - это сын. Практически это отчество, вроде наших Петрович (сын Петра), Иванович. Но в качестве примера приведу построение тюркских имен. Полное имя: Ибрагим Али-оглы, которое означает: Ибрагим сын Али." - сын Робина - Робинович?